# Can't fill in list with numbers

Tags: c++

I've written a program to make a list and put numbers into it, but after I put two numbers into it I get an error. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting that error? And is there are easy way to work with lists?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element element;
struct element
{
    int val;
    struct element *suiv;
};

typedef element* liste;

element* creer_cellule()
{
    element* nouv;
    nouv=(element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
    if (nouv==NULL)
    {
        printf("erreur memoire pleine");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        nouv->suiv=NULL;
        printf("donner un entier");
        scanf("%d",&nouv->val);
    }
}

void inserer_queue(element* t)
{
    element*nouv,*p;
    nouv=creer_cellule();
    p=t;
    while(p->suiv!=NULL)
    {
        p=p->suiv;
    }
    p->suiv=nouv;
}

void affiche_liste (element*t)
{
    element* p;
    p=t;
    while(p!=NULL)
        printf("%d",p->val);
}

void main(){
    element* tete=NULL;
    int i,n;
    printf("donner le nombre d'etudiants");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    tete=creer_cellule();
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        inserer_queue(tete);
        affiche_liste(tete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the C tag is more appropriate?

Comment: What is the error you see?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that `creer_cellule()` does not return the allocated object, thus in main you're working with an invalid pointer.